# The actual HTML link is offset (not 'anchored') to the text, IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

If you visit my website in Chrome, the menu links in the Header work normally. However, in Internet Explorer (utilizing 11, to be specific) if you hover the mouse over 'HOME' 'LISTINGS' or 'AGENTS' you'll see that the url shown on mouseover is actually not the correct link at all and, in fact, there is a hyperlink underline under a different word than you are hovering over.

Specific example, when hovering over 'LISTINGS' the URL that pops on mouseover is for the 'HISTORY' page and the hyperlink underline, indeed, shows up under 'HISTORY'. If you move the mouse to the LEFT of 'HOME' you'll see the links continue to pop way off of the header - it's as if the text for the menu is centered on the page properly, but the hyperlinks themselves begin at the very left edge of the page.

If you visit my site, the problem should be evident... hopefully I explained it well. I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out - again, it works perfect in Chrome but, in IE only, I have this problem.

http://www.brooksrealtysvc.com

Hopefully someone can help me figure out this issue... This is a company site and, therefore, I really need to make sure it is working properly in the big browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I'm not 100% sure if this will solve your problem, but here are my thoughts on this.

In Internet Explorer 9, the site worked fine for me - when the Document Mode was set to IE9 standards. Interestingly, the document initially loaded up in IE7 standards, but switching them to IE8 or higher resolved the link problems.

It looks like a `<meta>` tag in the document `<head>` which is the culprit:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

You can probably guess from this line why the document loaded up in IE7 mode for me, something which is probably also happening to you when you're using IE11. You could change the line to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This would cause Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available, rendering the page properly (at least with regards to the links) for both of us. Unfortunately, this doesn't address the website's incompatibility with IE7; it just prevents higher versions of IE from suffering from it.

(Sorry, I can't offer a solution for the latter issue, since I'm not well-versed with the nuances of that browser version. I think IE7 has dropped below 1% in worldwide usage by now though, so it's up to you whether you want to pursue this further.)

Hope this helps, anyways! I always find Internet Explorer to be a bit trickier to work with.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem... I don't mind if IE7 doesn't work... so long as the newer versions work, I'm covered. Many thanks for your help!